# How could I convert a bat code into a cs?

Tags: c#, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program in visual studio and I want this program to do this things, so I need the code to do it, I'm not a professional with cs.
Here is my batch file code :

```
@ echo off
color c
IF "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" (
SET HOSTFILE=%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
) ELSE (
SET HOSTFILE=%windir%\hosts
)

ECHO.>> %HOSTFILE%
ECHO "my ip" download.talesrunner.com>> %HOSTFILE%
IPCONFIG -flushdns
CLS
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: nope.. :| i want to edit the host file in this folder, "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc"

Comment: @MahmoudFaour added a fully translated code for you!

Comment: @cramopy thank you so much i will test it, i really appreciate it c:

Comment: @MahmoudFaour No problem, that's what `SO` is for!! Also thank/click the Upvote button :D ^^ Thx a lot for that!

Comment: @cramopy is there anywhere to contact you? cuz im having some problems.. :|

Comment: @cramopy never mind i fixed it c: and thanks again it worked ;)

Comment: @MahmoudFaour so please do me a favor and upvote my answer? :D THX!

Comment: @cramopy i tried but it didnt work, i dont know whos voting down my question lol i need reputations to do that lmao..

Comment: @cramopy hello, I need another favor, this code is working all fine thanks for helping me, but is there a way to make it delete all the lines then add this one? because if I keep opening the exe file it'll add new line, what I'm askin for if there is a way to delete what the text file have and replace this one, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I translated it into including color setment and using the safe `Path.Combine` way. It is now completely translated from your code!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("dnsapi", EntryPoint = "DnsFlushResolverCache")]
        private static extern uint DnsFlushResolverCache();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string varibale for hostilfe
            var HOSTFILE = "";

            //set to color c => red
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            //Get OperatingSystem information from the system namespace.
            var OSInfo = Environment.OSVersion;

            //Determine the platform.
            if (OSInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                //is windows NT
                HOSTFILE = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), @"system32\drivers\etc\hosts");
            }
            else
            {
                //is no windows NT
                HOSTFILE = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "hosts");
            }

            //print hostfile
            Console.WriteLine(HOSTFILE);

            //get ip address
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            var myIP = host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();

            //append newline & myip to hostfile
            File.AppendAllLines(HOSTFILE, new[] { "", $"{myIP} download.talesrunner.com" });

            //if the above does not work because you don't have C# 6.0 use the following line
            //File.AppendAllLines(HOSTFILE, new[] { "", string.Format("{0} download.talesrunner.com", myIP)});

            //flush dns cache
            DnsFlushResolverCache();

            //wait for user or sth else unless window will close immediately
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```